# taking a mathematica notebook on the cloud, mathlink applications, data file input and turning it into an API

Tags: wolfram-cloud, api

I have several mathematica applications, usually made of a single notebook calling several .m files and usually importing data from some datafiles (.txt) and linking some external mathlink applications.

Example toy model, Initialization part (that ideally I would like to keep hidden from eyes):

```
data=Readlist["datafile.txt"];
(*data={{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}*)

(*Parameters: values necessary for computations*)
xmin=1;
xmax=3;
xstep=0.1;

(*functions: definitions of functions necessary for computations*)
f1[x_]:=2x-1;

(*routines: compute something, maybe do that many times*)
Initf2:=(
f2=Interpolation[data];
)
getMyResult[x_]:=(
res=x/.NSolve[f1[x]-f2[x]==0,x];
Return[x];
)
Getresults:=(
Results={};
While[y=xmin,y<=xmax,y=y+xstep,
AppendTo[Results,{y,getMyResult[y]}];
];
Return[Results]
)
```

Running Part

```
(*here something to laod previous code*)
(*here something to maybe overwrite data with user provided datafile*)
Initf2;
Getresults
```

Question 1: it is possible to bring them to the cloud to be able to be run/be evaluated on the cloud? How to?

Question 2: If I publish the application on the cloud, it is possible to make public only the interface notebook (.nb) but not the associated functions in the .m files?

Question 3a: It is somehow possible to allow the user to evaluate the notebook using its own input file (.txt) instead of the default one loaded on the cloud? To make it more clear, lets say the datafile on cloud is in data/datafile.txt, and that the notebook when initialised usually reads that file and after that can run the computations. It is possible to let the user upload his own datafile.txt to be used in the computation, but without overwriting the default datafile (so that the new datafile is used only in that session for that user)

Question 3b: Let-s say that the computations require multiple steps, and that intermediate results are also stored in datafiles (intermediateresults1.txt, intermediateresults2.txt,...). In such case, when using an alternative input datafile, also the intermediate results will change. Again, is there a way to allow the user to run the application and let him have hiw own intermediate results datafiles (intermediateresults1.txt, intermediateresults2.txt,...) just for that session, without overwriting the default ones on cloud? On desktop to do this I usually create a duplicate folder of the program, let it run and overwrite default datafiles, and then delete at the end of the session. Is this somehow possible?

Question 4: is there any problem using external mathlink aplications, loaded with Install[app]? For what OS should they be compiled, in case?

Question 5: how to turn the notebook in an API? Ideally, it would be nice to be able to call the API by giving as input the datafile to upload, and returning the final result (I don't know if the compuitation time could be a problem here)

Question 6: ideally, I'd like the user to be able to do something like this. On his desktop mathematica, write something laod[linktoimyapp], to load the app, then usefile[datafile.txt] to load his datafile, and then call the function to run, with intermediate and final results saved locally. Alternatively, do the same from the cloud without owning a mathematica license. Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Those are many questions and neither code nor hint showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added an example toy model of a potential app.

Comment: It is better (& expected) to split this into the 7 different questions that you attempt to ask under the purview of one single question here. This is for your benefit & the benefit of those answering the questions. as well as current & future users.